# New lines not generating a textLineFragment when using a custom NSTextContentManager

Tags: cocoa, textkit

I have a custom subclass to a `NSTextContentManager` which provides `NSTextParagrah`s for layout. However, when I have a trailing newline in my content string, the `NSTextLayoutFragment` does not have a empty `NSTextLineFragment` indicating a new line. This is in contrast to using the standard `NSTextContentStorage`. `NSTextContentStorage` also uses `NSTextParagraph`s to represent it's text elements.

The code I have for both scenarios are

1. Using Default `NSTextContentStorage`

```
let layoutManager = NSTextLayoutManager()
let container = NSTextContainer(size: NSSize(width: 400, height: 400))
layoutManager.textContainer = container
let contentStorage = NSTextContentStorage()
contentStorage.textStorage?.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: 0), with: "It was the best of times.\n")
contentStorage.addTextLayoutManager(layoutManager)
layoutManager.enumerateTextLayoutFragments(from: contentStorage.documentRange.location, options: .ensuresLayout) { textLayoutFragment in
    print("defaultTextLineFragments:")
    for (index, textLineFragment) in textLayoutFragment.textLineFragments.enumerated() {
        print("\(index): \(textLineFragment)")
    }

    print("\n")
    return true
}
```

This outputs

```
defaultTextLineFragments:
0: <NSTextLineFragment: 0x123815a80 "It was the best of times.
">
1: <NSTextLineFragment: 0x123825b00 "">
```

2. Using custom subclass to `NSTextContentManager`

```
class CustomTextLocation: NSObject, NSTextLocation {

    let offset: Int

    init(offset: Int) {
        self.offset = offset
    }

    func compare(_ location: NSTextLocation) -> ComparisonResult {
        guard let location = location as? CustomTextLocation else {
            return .orderedAscending
        }

        if offset < location.offset {
            return .orderedAscending
        } else if offset > location.offset {
            return .orderedDescending
        } else {
            return .orderedSame
        }
    }
}

class CustomStorage: NSTextContentManager {

    let content = "It was the best of times.\n"

    override var documentRange: NSTextRange {
        NSTextRange(location: CustomTextLocation(offset: 0), end: CustomTextLocation(offset: content.utf8.count))!
    }

    override func textElements(for range: NSTextRange) -> [NSTextElement] {
        let paragraph = NSTextParagraph(attributedString: NSAttributedString(string: content))
        paragraph.textContentManager = self
        paragraph.elementRange = documentRange

        return [paragraph]
    }

    override func enumerateTextElements(from textLocation: NSTextLocation?, options: NSTextContentManager.EnumerationOptions = [], using block: (NSTextElement) -> Bool) -> NSTextLocation? {
        // Just assuming static text elements for this example
        let elements = self.textElements(for: documentRange)
        for element in elements {
            block(element)
        }

        return elements.last?.elementRange?.endLocation
    }

    override func location(_ location: NSTextLocation, offsetBy offset: Int) -> NSTextLocation? {
        guard let location = location as? CustomTextLocation,
              let documentEnd = documentRange.endLocation as? CustomTextLocation else {
            return nil
        }

        let offset = CustomTextLocation(offset: location.offset + offset)
        if offset.compare(documentEnd) == .orderedDescending {
            return nil
        }

        return offset
    }

    override func offset(from: NSTextLocation, to: NSTextLocation) -> Int {
        guard let from = from as? CustomTextLocation,
              let to = to as? CustomTextLocation else {
            return 0
        }

        return to.offset - from.offset
    }

}

let customLayoutManager = NSTextLayoutManager()
let customContainer = NSTextContainer(size: NSSize(width: 400, height: 400))
customLayoutManager.textContainer = customContainer
let customStorage = CustomStorage()
customStorage.addTextLayoutManager(customLayoutManager)

customLayoutManager.enumerateTextLayoutFragments(from: customStorage.documentRange.location, options: .ensuresLayout) { textLayoutFragment in
    print("customStorage textLineFragments:")

    for (index, textLineFragment) in textLayoutFragment.textLineFragments.enumerated() {
        print("\(index): \(textLineFragment)")
    }

    print("\n")
    return true
}
```

This outputs

```
customStorage textLineFragments:
0: <NSTextLineFragment: 0x13ff0c8d0 "It was the best of times.
">
```

I am expecting the two outputs to match (as it's impacting my position calculations for carets during text entry). How would I go about getting the text layout manager to add the extra line fragment while using a custom `NSTextContentManager`

**Update**

Based on additional testing, it looks like if `NSTextParagraph` has `paragraphSeparatorRange` set on it, then `NSTextLayoutManager` generates the additional text line fragment. There seem to be a couple of issues here.

1. `NSTextParagraph.paragraphSeparatorRange` is not settable by any public method. It has to be via unsupported `setValue(_:forKey:)`. I have a separate thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77587650/computation-of-nstextparagraph-paragraphseparatorrange?noredirect=1#comment136784263_77587650) on this.
2. By the looks of it, the type of `NSTextRange` has to be `NSCountableTextRange`. Any other kind of `NSTextRange` does not generate the `NSTextLayoutFragment`. Unfortunately, `NSCountableTextRange` is private as well. Even if we could use it, I guess there would be a mismatch between the `NSTextParagraph`'s elementRange type and that being used in the parent document.

Comment: `CustomTextLocation` must override `isEqual(_:)`, see [Compare NSTextRange for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77293163/compare-nstextrange-for-equality).

Comment: @Willeke thanks. I did have that in my original code base, but, missed it out while trying to reproduce this issue in a reduced code base. if you'd like to enter that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.