# Computation of NSTextParagraph.paragraphSeparatorRange

Tags: appkit, textkit

I'm trying to figure out how the properties `paragraphSeparatorRange` and `paragraphContentRange` are computed/set on a `NSTextParagraph`.

With the code below, neither of the properties are set.

```
var paragraph = NSTextParagraph(attributedString: NSAttributedString(string: "It was the best of times.\n"))
print("attributes: \(paragraph.attributedString.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil))")
print("paragraphSeparatorRange: \(String(describing: paragraph.paragraphSeparatorRange))")
print("paragraphContentRange: \(String(describing: paragraph.paragraphContentRange))")
```

However, when using `NSTextLayoutManager`/`NSTextContentStorage` they are set.

```
let layoutManager = NSTextLayoutManager()
let container = NSTextContainer(size: NSSize(width: 400, height: 400))
layoutManager.textContainer = container
let contentStorage = NSTextContentStorage()
contentStorage.textStorage = NSTextStorage(string: "It was the best of times.\n")
contentStorage.addTextLayoutManager(layoutManager)
layoutManager.enumerateTextLayoutFragments(from: contentStorage.documentRange.location, options: .ensuresLayout) { textLayoutFragment in
    print("layoutFragment: \(textLayoutFragment)")
    print("textElement: \(String(describing: textLayoutFragment.textElement))")
    print("textElement.range: \(String(describing: textLayoutFragment.textElement?.elementRange))")
    let paragraph = textLayoutFragment.textElement as! NSTextParagraph
    print("paragraphContentRange: \(String(describing: paragraph.paragraphContentRange))")
    print("paragraphSeparatorRange: \(String(describing: paragraph.paragraphSeparatorRange))")
 
    
    return true
}
```

Would appreciate any ideas on how these values are computed/set. Thanks

Comment: The values are computed with `NSString. getParagraphStart(_:end:contentsEnd:for:)` and the properties are set with private methods.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you. When using the method `getParagraphStart(_:end:contentsEnd:for:)` the correct indices are indeed returned. But, does that mean there is no way to have these set correctly on `NSTextParagraph` instance (similar to how `NSTextContentManager` seems to be doing)?

Comment: `NSTextParagraph`'s `paragraphContentRange` and `paragraphSeparatorRange` are readonly. There's no public API to set them. Unsupported workaround: `setValue(_:forKey:)`.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you. If you'd like to reply with an answer on this I'd be happy to accept it. I have another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569002/new-lines-not-generating-a-textlinefragment-when-using-a-custom-nstextcontentman) on what sparked this thread. If you have any thoughts on that, I'd appreciate it as well :-)